# openSUSE Leap 42.3 python repo

Tags: python, repository, supervisord, opensuse

to setup my VM I need to install python in openSUSE Leap 42.3 to get supervisord working.

Until last week I think this repo was working but now is gone:
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/

Any ideas where I can find it now or why it was removed?

Answer (score 0):

see content of one level up (https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python/) :

openSUSE_Leap_42.3 has been dropped in favor of openSUSE_Leap_15.0